# new Thread(runnable).start() doesnt work properly but run() does

Tags: java, multithreading, random, runnable, predicate

I'm trying to learn more about Threads and how they work.
I'd like to use a PrintStream and write random double values to a file until my Predicate stops it.

This is my Main class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Internet\\Desktop\\test123.txt");

        try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file); PrintStream print = new PrintStream(out)) {
            if (!file.exists())
                file.createNewFile();
            Predicate<Integer> pred = new CountPredicate(5);
            Runnable runnable = new RandomWriteRunner(pred, print);
            new Thread(runnable).start();
            //PrintStream p = r.getPrintStream();
            //runnable.run();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my class CountPredicate which implements Predicate and uses test() to determine whether the stop criteria is reached.

```
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class CountPredicate implements Predicate<Integer> {
    private int max;

    public CountPredicate(int max) {
        this.max = max;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(Integer current) {
        return current >= max;
    }
}
```

And this is my RandomWriteRunner class which implements Runnable and uses the constructor to give the run() method its values to work with.

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class RandomWriteRunner implements Runnable {
    private Random random;
    private Predicate<Integer> stopCriterion;
    private int generatedSoFar;
    private PrintStream printStream;

    public RandomWriteRunner(Predicate<Integer> stopCriterion, PrintStream printStream) {
        random = new Random();
        this.stopCriterion = stopCriterion;
        generatedSoFar = 0;
        this.printStream = printStream;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!stopCriterion.test(generatedSoFar)) {
            printStream.println(random.nextDouble());
            generatedSoFar++;
            System.out.println(generatedSoFar);
        }
    }

    public PrintStream getPrintStream() {
        return this.printStream;
    }
}
```

Since i cant access the printStream variable, because its private, i use a Getter to play with it in my Main class.

I tried writing this:

```
RandomWriteRunner r = new RandomWriteRunner(pred, print);
Runnable runnable = r;
new Thread(runnable).start();
PrintStream p = r.getPrintStream();
p.print('a');
```

Normally i would open my txt file and it would be empty but this time it said 'a' and a random double number. Why does it do that? And are those 6 random double values still in my PrintStream? 
When i use `new Thread(runnable).run();` it works but i heard thats because the run() method is called from my current Thread and thats not what i want. Also when i use the code as it is and add the `runnable.run()` written as a comment in my Main class my console shows the values from 1 to 6 instead of 1 to 5.
The reason why im so confused is that the run method is obviously called since my console shows me the `System.out.println(generatedSoFar);`
but it doesnt print the random double numbers to the file.
Am i missing something obvious? Thanks for all answers.

Comment: You are closing the stream immediately after starting the thread, because you exit the try-with-resources block. Store the thread in a variable, start it, then join it.

Comment: Thank you. That helped. So the join() method stops the Thread after its done? So when i got a result from p.print('a') and a random number it was because i gave the program enough time to write down instead of instantly closing it?

Comment: @Ikaros97 Re, " the join() method stops the Thread after its done?" No. A `t.join()` call  only _waits_ for thread `t` to finish. It doesn't do anything _to_ the thread.

Comment: I tried creating a Thread[] and put Objects from a class which implements Runnable in it. I normally learned that i use Runnable runnable = new ExampleClass(...);
Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
But just now i realized that i just put an object from a class into the Thread Array without any problems. Can i do that just because the class implemented the Interface? Always thought i need to put the object into a Runnable object first to feed it to a Thread. Thanks for any help